# dictionary keys sorted by value

Tags: python

I have this:

`{1: 'Foo', 2: 'Bar', 3: 'Chazz', 4: 'Alpha', 6: 'Zorn', 7: 'Doe'}`

And I want a list of the keys in the dict sorted alphabetically by the values:

`[4,2,3,7,1,6]`

What's the simplest, most pythonic approach that works in 2.7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> d = {1: 'Foo', 2: 'Bar', 3: 'Chazz', 4: 'Alpha', 6: 'Zorn', 7: 'Doe'}    
>>> sorted(d, key=d.get)
[4, 2, 3, 7, 1, 6]
```

Note that this is case sensitive. For example, if `"Bar"` were instead `"bar"`, the result of the above would have `2` at the very end of the list. In this case, you might want:

```
sorted(d, key=lambda x: d[x].lower())
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, this works just fine. not sure if there's a better/more pythonic way:

`sorted_list = sorted(a, key=a.get)`

Where `a` is the dict.